# print a string from a specific file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Let us suppose that there is a command such as:

```
# uname -a
Linux (none) 2.6.24 #155 PREEMPT Thu Nov 16 09:41:07 IST 2017 ppc GNU/Linux
```

Now, my question is: Are there any commands which will only print:

```
Nov 16 09:41:07 IST 2017
```

And could you please explain the command a little? Thank you! in advance.

Comment: Not sure what your application is. Are you looking for a command to extract 7th to 11th fields (delineated by blanks) of a line or are you asking to search a line to find a date, or are you asking to get the date of the kernel, or is this a homework assignment and your instructor lacks imagination and clear instructions?

Comment: Has any of the answers helped you? Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657) it or clarify your needs using [edit]ing or comments.

Answer (score 0):

This awk will do that using this variable:

```
uname -a | awk '{ print $7,$8,$9,$10,$11 }'
```

Result:

```
Nov 16 09:41:07 IST 2017
```

- `awk`: start awk program
- `'{ print $7,$8,$9 }'`: print the 7th, 8th and 9th fields with `,` spaces between these values.
- `uname -a |`: pipe the result of `uname -a` to the `awk` command for processing

Comment: This does not work in my case where the field count differs. `uname -a` gives `Linux MiM-testsrv-ubuntu 4.4.0-72-lowlatency #93-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 31 15:14:04 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`, the result of your command: `Fri Mar 31 15:14:04 UTC`

Comment: This is not a one-to-one support site but a public knowledge base, so we should post universally usable answers. If they have some caveats, we should warn about them.

Comment: Melebius Now, why would you assume OP wants to use the command `uname -v` rather than `uname -a` perhaps you know the OP? I don't second guess OPs I do as requested and add any extra for the general public.

Comment: As [WinEunuuchs2Unix correctly pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996424/print-a-string-from-a-specific-file#comment1609141_996424), the question is ambiguous. You chose one option from the possibilities mentioned by WinEunuuchs2Unix, I chose another. Hopefully, OP will come back and clarify their needs. In the meantime (which may also grow to infinity), we should clarify the assumptions valid for our solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The command `uname -a` prints all the information about your kernel while `uname -v` only prints kernel version which is the part ending with the date:

```
$ uname -v
#155 PREEMPT Thu Nov 16 09:41:07 IST 2017
```

You can use the [`tail -c`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163497/54675) command to print the end of the string with the specified length.

```
uname -v | tail -c25
```

This works well also in my case where the count of spaces differs.

```
$ uname -v
#93-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 31 15:14:04 UTC 2017
$ uname -v | tail -c25
Mar 31 15:14:04 UTC 2017
```

Comment: And what is the result of `uname -a | tail -c25` as I see OP used `uname -a` and not `uname -v`. Please direct your questions to Op to clarify any ambiguities!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I had explained it in the beginning of my answer. I’ve just added a bit more information, please check it now.